# What is the WHI-SelfServ project in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My GCP account has always had a project named WHI-SelfServ.  It seems to be the default login account, but I can't find any explanation or documentation of what it is.

Can the WHI-SelfServ project be used to deploy clusters, or should I create a separate project for that?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this behavior in GCP but I would recommend the following:

1. Create a new project aligned with what will be deployed there(i.e. production, development, staging, etc.).
2. Delete the **WHI-SelfServ** Project.
3. Start building cool stuff!

Answer (score 0):

There's no default hidden place-keeper project in your GCP (Google Cloud Platform) if that's what you are afraid of. It's probably just an API project you created to use APIs (APIs like Drive API,  Translate API) that requires a GCP project.

In another word, feel free to use it to start a cluster or anything else you desire on GCP.

If you run into actually issues with the project itself, contact Google Cloud Platform support and they will be able to assist you with it.